# execute photoshop action from VB UI

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb6, photoshop

i am new to this forum, so please excuse me if i ask any silly question.

I am trying to run photoshop action from VB interface.   can any body guide me on how should i proceed.

thank you

Comment: maybe using adobe sdk and win32 api is useful, give more details to get more details ;)

Comment: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Kindly read the [faq] -- question titles are supposed to be phrased as questions. You wouldn't walk up to someone and say "execute photoshop action from VB UI?" Also, it is expected that you demonstrate at least some effort in solving your problem. You need to state your goal, show what you have tried, and present a _specific_ issue preventing you from reaching that goal.

Comment: @user1445750: if any answer is useful, accept it and make its Tick Green!

Answer (score 3):

to interact with photoshop in c# you can see [this page](http://www.pcpix.com/Photoshop/), the simple and basic manual to scripting photoshop

Comment: thank you maziar, but i want to create a button by which i can execute photoshop action. can u suggest on this please. thank you

Comment: yes, its a photoshop macro and i want to program it with button

Comment: see suggested link at the end of my answer, interact with photoshop using COM interface

Comment: why the downvote? maybe a bad question but this is a good answer.

Comment: @JeremyThompson `this is a good answer` Link-only answers are frowned upon because they are subject to link rot (I didn't downvote). This is a long shot, but some people get upset when others try to answer questions that are likely to be closed.

Comment: @JP. Ok. I should have noticed, the article was good though. I've only recently got into the habit of copying with bibliographies myself if I need to.